# Reading unicode chars on the byte level

Tags: perl, unicode, byte

Suppose I wanted to detect unicode characters and encode them using `\u` notation. If I had to use a byte array, are there simple rules I can follow to detect groups of bytes that belong to a single character?

I am referring to UTF-8 bytes that need to be encoded for an ASCII-only receiver. At the moment, non-ASCII-Printable characters are stripped. `s/[^\x20-\x7e\r\n\t]//g`.

I want to improve this functionality to write `\u0000` notation.

Comment: `\u` has nothing _whatsoever_ to do with UTF8.

Comment: @SLaks, See my edits. Please let me know if I am unclear on anything.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have Unicode characters, so start by decoding your byte array.

```
use Encode qw( decode );
my $decoded_text = decode("UTF-8", $encoded_text);
```

Only then can you escape Unicode characters.

```
( my $escaped_text = $decoded_text ) =~
   s/([^\x0A\x20-\x5B\x5D-\x7E])/sprintf("\\u%04X", ord($1))/eg;
```

For example,

```
$ perl -CSDA -MEncode=decode -E'
   my $encoded_text = "\xC3\x89\x72\x69\x63\x20\xE2\x99\xA5\x20\x50\x65\x72\x6c";
   my $decoded_text = decode("UTF-8", $encoded_text);
   say $decoded_text;
   ( my $escaped_text = $decoded_text ) =~
      s/([^\x0A\x20-\x5B\x5D-\x7E])/sprintf("\\u%04X", ord($1))/eg;
   say $escaped_text;
'
Éric ♥ Perl
\u00C9ric \u2665 Perl
```

Comment: Note that this approach adds ambiguity: Codepoints over 0xFFFF will be indistinguishable from shorter codepoints followed by ASCII digits (also, it will escape most ASCII characters in the range 0 .. 31 including tab/carriage return (or newline on MacOS classic :-) - I'd just use `s/([^[:ascii:]])/.../eg` there).

Comment: There's nothing I can do about the scheme is not defined for codepoints over U+FFFF. Escaping control characters is a good thing.

Comment: I have no idea about perl but `\uxxxx` is defined for code points above U+FFFF using surrogate pairs: `\uHHHH\uLLLL`. For example, `U+20000`: `\ud840\udc00`

Comment: @Esailija, You're talking about JSON. The OP didn't mention anything about JSON. He asked to encode codepoints as `\uXXXX`. If he wants JSON, he should use JSON::XS.

Comment: @ikegami what do you mean JSON? I tested it in C#, java, javascript and python 2.7. These all support surrogate pairs in the \u notation for astral planes.

Comment: @Esailija, You're proving my point. He didn't specify that he wanted a C# literal, a Java literal, a JSON literal, etc. All he said is that he wanted `\uXXXX`. If he wants one of those you listed, he'll need to specify which one. Doing so would also require using the right kind of quotes and escaping them somehow.